# Add key/value items list to custom config element in C#

Tags: c#, configuration

I have a C# app that needs to pull configuration settings from the App.config file. In that file, I've defined a custom configuration element like this:

```
public class Node : ConfigurationElement
{
    public Node()
    { }

    [ConfigurationProperty("name", IsRequired=true, IsKey=true, DefaultValue="")]
    public string Name
    {
        get { return (string)(this["name"]); }
        set { this["name"] = value; }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("kind", IsRequired=false, IsKey=false)]
    public string Kind
    {
        get { return (string)(this["kind"]); }
        set { this["kind"] = value; }
    }
}
```

With this code, I can successfully add an element in my App.config file that looks like this:

```
<node name="V1" kind="test" />
```

I want to expand this element to mimic the `appSettings` element to allow child `add` elements like this:

```
<node name="V1" kind="test">
  <add key="property1" value="1" />
  <add key="property3" value="A" />
  <add key="property2" value="Z" />
  ...
</node>
```

My question is, how do I do that? Is there a specific collection type I need to use? Is it build it to .NET somehow? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I needed to use the `KeyValueConfigurationCollection` type on my Items property.